# C# Best way to calculate the hash of a string list plus two properties

Tags: c#, hash

I have an entity which has a property that holds a list of strings. The number of those strings may become really large (I have seen upto 10000 in one document). I'm looking for an efficient and clean way of calculating the hash of the strings as well as two boolean properties in the same document.  This operation may happen multiple times everyday, since the documents keep changing.

```
public class Document
{
   public List<string> ListOfStrings {get; set;}
   public bool BoolValue1 {get; set;}
   public bool BoolValue2 {get; set;}
}
```

I want to calculate and store the hash of the strings list combined with the two boolean values, so that I can easily compare these properties with those of other versions of this document.

Comment: would depends of what kind of hash you want, MD5, SHA256, SHA512 or others...... take a look at the System.Security.Cryptography namespace and google for examples.  then, set the order and the separator you want and hash it

Comment: Your object is mutable. That's usually a bad thing when computing hashes.

Comment: Hash the bool values and the first and last string in the list (be sure to handle empty lists). This will mean the hash operation takes a reasonably static period of time (never hashing more than 4 values).

Comment: @mjwills -- what if the list changes, but the first and last items don't change?

Comment: @Andy - If anything in an object changes the all bets are off. Hash codes must not change for the lifetime of the object for them to be effective.

Comment: @Enigmativity -- ok, thanks.. that makes sense.

Comment: @Andy - Firstly, Enigmativity is correct. Secondly, it is OK for two different objects to have the same hash.